# How to combine two inequality answers into the same line

Tags: python, jupyter, inequalities

So basically I'm being asked in class to solve an inequality -1<(7-x)/3<=4, and the teacher wants the answer of what will become two sets of code on the same line using `solveset`.
So this ends up being `solveset(-1<((7-x)/3),x,domain=S.Reals) and solveset (((7-x)/3)<=4,x,domain=S.Reals)`
But whenever I end up putting `&` or `and` in between them to get them on that same line output, I get either the answer to the first OR the answer to the second, which is the complete opposite of what I want. How should I be inputting this?
I'm using Jupyter Python stuff. Specifically we've imported sympy stuff.

Comment: What is your desired output format? Maybe a tuple `solevset(...), solveset(...)`?

Comment: the issue is that he wants it to ouput with something like Union(Interval.open(. . .), Interval.open(. . . )) If I do as you suggest I don't get the Union

Comment: `solveset(-1<((7-x)/3), x, domain=S.Reals) & solveset (((7-x)/3)<=4, x, domain=S.Reals)` will correctly give you the solution, i.e., `Interval.Ropen(-5, 10)` which means `[-5, 10)`

Comment: thank you abc! I have no clue what little thing I missed but it works on my end.

Answer (score 0):

abc has answered!
"solveset(-1<((7-x)/3), x, domain=S.Reals) & solveset (((7-x)/3)<=4, x, domain=S.Reals) will correctly give you the solution, i.e., Interval.Ropen(-5, 10) which means [-5, 10)"